# Negative search in find/grep pipeline not removing any records

Tags: awk, grep, find

I am struggling a bit with my bash find command.

The problem is a late requirement which wants me to strip off all records from *.app files containing *.appstrng"

This is my original find pipeline that is working flawlessly without the negative attempt to strip records:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.app" -exec grep -we selected_apps -e app_name --color=auto --with-filename {}         \; > LOG.txt
```

Now here are some of the attempts I have made to add stripping of .appstring before creating LOG.txt

1) With grep -v

```
find . -type f -iname "*.app" -exec grep -we selected_apps -e app_name -ev "*.appstring" --color=auto --with-filename {} \; > LOG.txt
```

2) With awk

```
find . -type f -iname "*.app" -exec grep -we selected_apps --color=auto --with-filename {} \; | awk '!/*.appstring/' > LOG.txt
```

I am not sure if find/grep or find/awk will even work in this way... all comments welcomed! Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks but... 1) if this is 'global' wont the positive, original search also be effected.  2) I am not sure how this would be added to the full pipe?  very new here.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your original command and remove some results with an additional command:

```
cat LOG.txt | while read FILE; do
    if ! grep -q "*.appstring" "$FILE"; then
        echo $FILE >> LOG-filtered.txt
    fi
done
```